# Why the references are not downloaded from scopus to be shown in Biblioshiny?

Tags: scopus

When I try to do any analysis that deals with references of the metadata that I downloaded from Scopus, I get all sorts of errors. My colleagues experienced the same thing. I saw that there is no references that was downloaded in the first place (please look at the red rows below), even though I had checked all the boxes. Has anyone got any solution for this?
[image]

Bibliometrix and Biblioshiny are my tools